# How to make other components listen when one particular component emit something, Stackblitz demo included

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have following situation, I have Player component which receives array of number as an input, on user action that component emits max number from that array.

Next to that component there is one or multiple Bot components, once Player component do it's thing, Bot component should synchronously emit max number from array they received and I should have information which Bot component returned which number and in which order. I also have redux integrated but not sure how store can help me with this.

Big thanks in advance! Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wqroju

Comment: you heard about rxJs?

Comment: redux share global state if you dont want to use rxjs then you will have to work around for a solution as the only problem is to notify or listen on changes a solution for this would be default component ,then all of your components extend it, then implement observable pattern -inside the default component- for the global state (redux), i can provide an example if you want

Comment: @youssef I've started working on redux/store like solution and would like to see store like solution/example

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tpm5fp 
look at this example using rxjs player inform bot he needs max number bots send him max number in the array and remove it from array